# Express server skipping if statement and sending response to POST request

Tags: json, express, post, server, client

I am making a battleship game using JS with a client-server communication interface.

In my client I send the tile that is clicked by the user on the CPU gameboard to the server to check if it is a HIT or a MISS and depending on that the server responds at which point the gameboard updates to show whether a ship was hit or not.

this is the part my server that responds to hit/miss:

```
        // generate cpu attack
        var tileToAttack = cpuAttack(dataIn['cpuhitship']);

        // cpu tile being attacked by player
        var tileXY = dataIn['tileattacked'];        

        // check if a CPU ship placed on the selected tile
        if(allCoords.includes(tileXY)){

            // remove tile from array
            var index = allCoords.indexOf(tileXY);
            if(index != -1){
            allCoords.splice(index, 1);
            } 

            // check if ship is destroyed
            cpuShipDestroyed(tileXY);            

            // send back hit response and cpu attack
            var jsontext = JSON.stringify({
                task:'cpuHit',                      
                tilehit:tileXY,
                message:'HIT! BOOOOM!',
                carrierlength:carrier.length,
                battleshiplength:battleship.length,
                submarinelength:submarine.length,
                cruiserlength:cruiser.length,
                patrolboatlength:patrolboat.length,
                cpucoords:allCoords.length,
                cpuattack:tileToAttack                            
            });
            res.send(jsontext);            
        }    
        else{

            // send back miss response and cpu attack
            var jsontext = JSON.stringify({
                task: 'cpuMiss',
                tilemiss:tileXY,
                cpuattack:tileToAttack,                               
                message:'MISS! All you hear is the missile hitting water!'
            });

            res.send(jsontext);
            console.log(jsontext);          
        }
```

this my JSON object i am sending

```
// get coordinates of the tile being attacked
var attackXY = parseInt(cpuTile.substring(8, 10));

var data = 
            {
                task:'playerAttack',                
                tileattacked:attackXY      
            };             

 $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json' 
              }).done(function(response) {
```

tileXY is an integer corresponding to a tile on the gameboard. Example 12 would be 1 tile X and 2 tiles Y.

allCoords stores 17 integers which correspond to CPU ship placement.

However, I am only sent back the miss response even if I do hit the correct tile; it skips the if statement and goes to the else{} part everytime. Any clue as to what might be happening?

Comment: If you're talking about the code always skipping `if(allCoords.includes(tileXY)){`, then apparently that statement is always `false` so you have to do some debugging to figure out why that is.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok for some reason the JSON data that contains the integer corresponding to a tile doesnt seem to work with includes() or even index() functions for arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to use parseInt().